# Multithread foreach hashmap loop

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, jsoup

I am storing data retrieved with the help of JSoup and submit them to my own HTTP API.

The problem: How can I iterate over my `HashMap` with multithreads, without each thread treat the same value of my `HashMap` like it is the case currently.

Actually:

```
Thread1: a  
Thread2: a  
Thread3: a  
Thread4: a  

Thread1: b  
Thread2: b  
Thread3: b  
Thread4: b
```

I want something like this:

```
Thread1 : a 
Thread2 : b
Thread3 : c
Thread4 : d
```

```java
package ygg.org;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Filmstreaming1 {

    final static int NB_PAGE = 2;
    final static int THREADS = 1;
    static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> movies_list = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    static int count = 0;

    static void Initialize() {

        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Homer is starting...");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= NB_PAGE ; i++) {
            try {

                Document page = Jsoup.connect("http://xxxxxxx.com/page/" + i + "/")
                                    .userAgent("Mozilla")
                                    .timeout(3000)
                                    .post();
                Elements movies = page.getElementsByClass("margin-b40").get(0).getElementsByClass("short-link").select("a");
                for (Element movie : movies) {
                    String href = movie.attr("href");
                    String movie_title = movie.text().replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");
                    boolean isMovieExists = movies_list.containsKey(href);
                    if (isMovieExists == false) {
                        movies_list.put(href, movie_title);
                        System.out.println("Ajout du film " + movie_title);
                    }                          
                }
                System.out.println("Total récupérés " + movies_list.size() + " page : " + i);
            } catch(IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + ioe);
            }
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i <= THREADS; i++) {
                Thread api = new ThreadApi();
                api.start();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class ThreadApi extends Thread {

    public void  run() {
        while(true) {

            Filmstreaming1.movies_list.forEach((key, value) -> {

                try {

                    String code = key.substring(key.indexOf("com/") + 4, key.indexOf("-"));

                    Document page = Jsoup.connect("http://xxxxxxx.com/" + code + "--.html")
                                                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                                                .timeout(3000)
                                                .post();

                    String director = page.getElementsByClass("finfo-text").get(5).text().toString();

                    Document page1 = Jsoup.connect("http://xxxxxxx.com/play.php?newsid=" + code + "&vt=ol&sr=3")
                                                .referrer("http://xxxxxxx.com/" + code + "--.html")
                                                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                                                .timeout(3000)
                                                .post();


                    String link = page1.getElementsByTag("iframe").first().attr("src").toString();

                    String encoded_title = URLEncoder.encode((String) value, "UTF-8");
                    String encoded_director = URLEncoder.encode((String) director, "UTF-8");

                    String url = "http://xxxxxxx.com/api/movie?movie=" + encoded_title + "&director=" + encoded_director;

                    // On affiche l'url 
                    System.out.println(url);

                    Document api = Jsoup.connect(url)
                                                .userAgent("Mozilla") 
                                                .timeout(3000)
                                                .get();

                    String response = api.text();
                    System.out.println(response);
                    if (response == "-1") {
                        System.out.println("Erreur");       

                    } else {

                        url = "http://xxxxxxx.com/api/video?link=" + link + "&ref=" + response + "&version=vf";             

                        Document submit = Jsoup.connect(url)
                                                    .userAgent("Mozilla") 
                                                    .timeout(3000)
                                                    .get();

                        response = submit.text();

                        Filmstreaming1.movies_list.remove(key);
                        System.out.println(response);
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Exception " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using some higher-level abstraction instead of creating the Threads yourself. Have a look at the [Oracle Tutorials for parallel Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html)

Comment: So Hard for a java beginner ^^

Comment: Well, multithreading is a pretty advanced topic in any language.

Comment: Also have a look at [ConcurrentHashMap.forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#forEach-long-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

Comment: Of course , but i ll try to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `Map` is already a `ConcurrentHashMap`, you could just use [ConcurrentHashMap.forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#forEach-long-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) - this allows to configure a `paralleslismThreshold` which may automatically execute the invocations in parallel if the threshold is exceeded.

The Docs have the following to say about the effects of the threshold parameter:

> These bulk operations accept a parallelismThreshold argument. Methods proceed sequentially if the current map size is estimated to be less than the given threshold. Using a value of Long.MAX_VALUE suppresses all parallelism. Using a value of 1 results in maximal parallelism by partitioning into enough subtasks to fully utilize the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() that is used for all parallel computations. Normally, you would initially choose one of these extreme values, and then measure performance of using in-between values that trade off overhead versus throughput.

So no need for creating your own `Thread` or even `Runnable`-implementation, any method reference or lambda that acts as a `BiConsumer<? super K,? super V>` will do.

Comment: Possible to add me skype ?